# How to remove empty classes from legend in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, arcmap, legend

I have a classification image with only 12 classes. I'm preparing layout using this image. when I add legend into layout page, a lot of empty classes loaded together with these 12 classes. Totally 255 classes added to layout page. Then I tried to delete them in Symbology tab of data Properties window. How to remove these empty classes from legend.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What kind of data do you have? Are the classes numeric? In that case you could change the classes' range in Symbology (click Classify). If not, maybe you can post some screenshots to visualize?

Comment: These classes are not numeric, named just like forest, water etc..., When I tried to change these range, the result was still the same with befor it was.

Comment: How can I separate legends one by one? After separating them, I wanna delete empty arrays.

Comment: If you [Convert a map element to graphics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/#/Working_with_legends/00s900000023000000/) you can ungroup the legend graphics so the individual elements can be edited individually. Now the legend can be edited individually. But then it is **not** a dynamic legend. If you change the color of the layer the color of the legend will not change.

Comment: Jens - too much work to do that ! For a large raster dataset you wouldn't want that if you need to classified or clipped to a smaller area.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on Legend rectangle and select properties, legend properties will open. Select items and in the item screen there a block named map extend options.
Check the box of (only show classes that are visible in the current map extent)

Answer (score 1):

Have you build the Raster Attribute Table when you classified the classification image ? I had to do that when I clipped from an original GAP or NLCD imagery and need to clip to a vector/polygon. For example, here is what happened, when you clip to a vector, it brings the  whole bunch of legneds carried over from the original imagery to the clipped imagery and I had to build the Raster Attribute Table toolbox to clean up the table in the clipped imagery. This way you will not have to convert them to graphics and lined up the symbology and that is pain !

It works for me and really saved a lot of my time and when I change it to the layout page and it will display what you need right there !

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the legend, grouping -> disaggregate, disaggregate again, then you can delete each individual component. When you are done, select all components and re-group them. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that new for ArcGIS 10 and later version ? - Daniel

Comment: It actually might be. I don't have access to prior versions so I couldn't tell you for sure. It's the method I've been using, though.

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I don't remember it when I had the 9.3.1 but now I have the 10 version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes build raster attribute table but in cataloge and it will update the new legend